# Mail recipient name with accents

Tags: linux, mail-command

## Context

```
$ echo $LANG
fr_FR.UTF-8
```

## Problem

While it is possible to have accents in the sender name, `mail` seems to not accept them in recipient name:

- `mail -s "Test" -r "Denis Bitouzé <denis.bitouze@test.fr>" "Denis Bitouze <denis.bitouze@test.org>" < /dev/null` OK, returns (blind translation from French): `mail: Message content empty; hopes it's correct`
- `mail -s "Test" -r "Denis Bitouzé <denis.bitouze@test.fr>" "Denis Bitouzé <denis.bitouze@test.org>" < /dev/null` not OK, returns (blind translation from French): `mail: Impossible to parse the address « Denis Bitouzé <denis.bitouze@test.org> » (when expanding « Denis Bitouzé <denis.bitouze@test.org> ») : Wrong address syntax`

## Question

Is it possible for `mail` recipient name to contain accents?

Comment: what mail transport agent are you using ? postfix ? sendmail ? there should be some parameter telling to use 8bit char.

Comment: If I'm sure it'snot `sendmail` (not installed on my system), I must admit I'm not sure for `postfix` (installed on my system). How to check this?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Apologies for the tardy response Denis.  As you can see that one simple question resulted in me going deep down the rabbit hole and rebuilding my Postfix server to a more modern version number.  Anyway, yours was an interesting problem to solve!

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer:

Yes, it's possible to send email to recipients with accented characters. **HOWEVER**:

**Support from both the sending mailserver, receiving mailserver *and all SMTP servers that route the mail between them* MUST support UTF8.**

From below tests using gMail to send the email with the accented character, this implies gMail has the required UTF8 support (even if they didn't let me create a mail account with accented characters) to route such mail.

### Long Answer:

I previously tested sending mail to recipients with accented characters in their email address using ***Postfix version 2.2***. Not by choice, but because it was the last supported version in my mailserver's RHEL7 repo. After all my tests sending mail to these accounts failed, I did some digging and found in the [Postfix README](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html) that:

> ...Introduced with ***Postfix version 3.0***, this fully supports UTF-8
>   email addresses and UTF-8 message header values.

So support for non-English characters very much appeared to be a function of support in the SMTP application itself from that sentence.  So I spun up a RHEL 8 AWS VM and configured ***Postfix version 3.3.1*** on it to test the UTF8 support.

I configured an email account "***tèrrence@test.com***" and sent mail to it from a gMail account.

### Client Side:

You'll remark from the header the mail sent to this account got there.  (Note I changed the name of email server, sender address and recipient domain in below output):

```
Return-Path: <testSender@gmail.com>
X-Original-To: tèrrence@test.com
Delivered-To: tèrrence@test.com
Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=209.85.222.196; helo=mail-qk1-f196.google.com; envelope-from=testSender@gmail.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN>
Received: from mail-qk1-f196.google.com (mail-qk1-f196.google.com [209.85.222.196])
        (using TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits))
        (No client certificate requested)
        by mail.postfix3server.org (Postfix) with UTF8SMTPS id EA3BB1C226AE
        for <tèrrence@test.com>; Thu, 12 Mar 2020 16:49:12 +0000 (GMT)
Received: by mail-qk1-f196.google.com with SMTP id p62so7358902qkb.0
        for <tèrrence@test.com>; Thu, 12 Mar 2020 09:49:12 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
         d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
         h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
         bh=+sxzWGIhDj27WByaDTDqzH+gvh5YvxK7AK8RkDc6r3g=;
         b=Blu+ <SNIP> cd
          wgdA==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
         d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
         h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
         bh=+sxz <SNIP> rwK
         L7Uw==
X-Gm-Message-State: ANhLgQ2NC <SNIP> aBaUf
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADFU+v <SNIP> KwMI=
X-Received: by 2002:ae9:dcc1:: with SMTP id q18 <SNIP> 88368;
Thu, 12 Mar 2020 09:48:08 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Terrence Houlahan <testSender@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 12 Mar 2020 16:47:31 +0000
Message-ID: <CAG6EasLnB4w_XzXPL4LcTuWrDWsQsvkGDj1-SSTgtJTzk_r0Cg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test 1 sending accented characters
To: tèrrence@test.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="0000000000001927fa05a0ab1ec0"

--0000000000001927fa05a0ab1ec0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
.
```

Remark the line in the above:

```
by mail.postfix3server.org (Postfix) with UTF8SMTPS
```

### Server Side:

From `/var/log/maillog` on the receiving mailserver for the address with the accented character:

```
postfix/smtpd[xxxx]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-qk1-f196.google.com[209.85.222.196]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
policyd-spf[xxxx]: prepend Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=209.85.222.196; helo=mail-qk1-f196.google.com; envelope-from=testSender@gmail.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN>
postfix/smtpd[xxxx]: EA3BB1C226AE: client=mail-qk1-f196.google.com[209.85.222.196]
postfix/cleanup[xxxx]: EA3BB1C226AE: message-id=<CAG6EasLnB4w_XzXPL4LcTuWrDWsQsvkGDj1-SSTgtJTzk_r0Cg@mail.gmail.com>
mail postfix/qmgr[xxxx]: EA3BB1C226AE: from=<testSender@gmail.com>, size=6579, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/virtual[xxxx]: EA3BB1C226AE: to=<tèrrence@test.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.32, delays=0.31/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
postfix/qmgr[xxxx]: EA3BB1C226AE: removed
```

### Conclusion:

So yes, you can use accented characters to send/receive mail, but the conditional on support in the chain of SMTP servers routing the mail to interpret them.  We see gMAil can do this and so can a properly configured Postfix server that's version 3 or greater. My testing is however limited to Postfix and can make no assertions on the UTF8 compatibility of other alternatives.

Comment: Do you mean `é` should be written `=C3=A9`?

Comment: Wow, this is a very deep rabbit hole.  Am in the process of updating my answer; will be done shortly-

Comment: I would have expected the `mail` client to perform that character mangling.